# SQL Query OneToMany Filtering with child entity but returning parent

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-data-jpa

Hey I need some help with an SQL Query I just can't figure out.
I got these two Tables with an OneToMany/ManyToOne relation:

```
create table Author (
"UUID" RAW(16) DEFAULT NULL NOT NULL ENABLE,
"name" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"processed" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE,
CONSTRAINT "Author_P" PRIMARY KEY ("UUID"),
)

create table Book (
"UUID" RAW(16) DEFAULT NULL NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"name" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"release" TIMESTAMP(6),
"AUTHOR_ID" RAW(16) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT Book_P PRIMARY KEY (UUID),
        CONSTRAINT Book_F FOREIGN KEY (KAFKA_BEZIEHUNG_ID) REFERENCES "Author" ("UUID")
)
```

Now I got this select query to get me all Books that have been written before the current date:

(I'm doing this in Java JPA via the Query Annotation)

```
@Query(Select b from Book b where b.release < current_timestamp)
List<Book> findAllBooksBeforeToday();
```

In this case I am returning all the books, but what I what instead is:

1. returning only the authors and without duplicates
2. Additional I only want to return the authors where the "processed" value is false.

I can achieve the first by doing this or atleast I thought but thats not quite working:

```
@Query(Select b.author_id from Book b where b.release < current_timestamp)
HashSet<Author> findAllBooksBeforeToday();
```

The second condition is pretty simple like this:

```
@Query(Select a from author a where a.processed = false)
```

So my question is now, how do I and maybe even can I combine these two queries in one query that selects from the book table but only returns the author that are processed = false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming Book.AUTHOR_ID matches Author.UUID

```
select distinct b.author_id 
from Book b inner join Author a on a.UUID = b.AUTHOR_ID
where a.processed = 0 and b.release < current_timestamp
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Only thing I changed was "select distinct b" instead of "b.author_id" since I want the complete entity not only the id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java, but - queries that do what you want (at least, how I understood it) are

```
-- distinct authors (i.e. no duplicates)
select distinct a.name
from author a;

-- "false" processed authors
select distinct a.name
from author a
where a.processed = 0;

-- join books and "false" processed authors
select b.name as book_name,
       a.name as author_name
from book b join author a on a.uuid = b.uuid
where a.processed = 0;
```